# Use Eisenstein´s criterion to show that $P(x)=x^n+5x^{n-1}+3$ is irreducible.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Since Eisenstein´s criterion ist not directly applicable we look at the polynomial P (mod 5), which then reduces to 
$P(x) = x^n + 3$ (mod 5) *... is this correct?*
Now I can apply the Eisenstein Criterion with prime number 3: The leading coefficient of $x^n$ is 1 and not divisible by 3. The other coefficients, 0 and 3 are divisible by the prime 3. Further, the constant, 3, ist not divisible by the square of the chosen prime, $3^2 = 9$. Therefore, $P$ is an irreducible polynomial.
Is this correct? Have I understood the E.C. correctly?

Comment: Worth noting:  I don't see how to use Eisenstein literally here, but a simple modification of the E.C. works fine, as is illustrated in the answers to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not correct. Eisenstein's criterion is for polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, not in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, for some prime $p$. For instance, by your argument, $x^2+5x+6$ would be irreducible. But it is reducible, since it is equal to $(x+2)(x+3)$.

Comment: Thank you - appreciated. I checked out on Eisenstein´s theorem and previous answers.

Comment: @Parzifal If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: your answer is marked. But if (and only if) you could spare a comment or two to explain how the Eisenstein criterion could be used for this task I would be more than grateful (I`m a high school student with not too much background). Thanks.

Comment: As much as I would love to help you, I see no way of using Eisenstein's criterion to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you anyway ... I was asked to use by my tutor to apply it, but I appreciate that it mustbe solved otherwise.